# Columna virtual calculada desde otra tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql

Quiero crear una columna de tipo stored en una tabla de mysql, *TBL_Account*.
Quiero que la columna almacene la suma de los valores de la columna *Debit*, que se encuentra en otra tabla: *TBL_Records*.

```sql
ALTER TABLE
  TBL_Account
ADD
  COLUMN Test DECIMAL(10, 2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SELECT SUM(Debit) FROM TBL_Records) STORED;
```

Pero quiero que solo sume aquellos valores para los que el valor de id en la tabla *TBL_Account* coincida con el valor de *FK_Account* en la tabla *TBL_Records*.

Comment: en SQL server se puede hacer algo por el estilo haciendo una función escalar e invocándola, a lo mejor te puede servir esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Comment: No se pueden usar ni subconsultas ni funciones de usuario en columnas generadas; además que la [*Normalización*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalización_de_bases_de_datos) sugiere -implícitamente- no almacenar datos calculados. Tu alternativa es una vista con consulta escalar.